Integration and expansion of hypergeometric function
I am trying to reproduce the evaluation of the expansion in $\epsilon$ for the function in Appendix B of the paper arxiv.org/abs/0705.0676v3, which involves the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\Delta V_{\mathrm{eff}}^{(c, d)}}{N} &= -\frac{4}{N}\left(1-\frac{1}{4 N}\right) \frac{\delta^2 \lambda^2 \eta^5}{(4 \pi)^{9 / 2}}\left(\frac{e^{\gamma_E} M^2}{\eta^2}\right)^{\frac{3 \epsilon}{2}} \Gamma\left(-\frac{5}{2}+\frac{3 \epsilon}{2}\right)(2-\epsilon)^2 \\
&\times \frac{\Gamma^2\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(-1+\epsilon)} \int_0^1 d \alpha d \beta[\beta(1-\beta)]^{-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}} {}_2 F_1\left[-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \frac{3}{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2},-1+\epsilon ; 1-z\right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $ z = \frac{\alpha(1-\alpha)}{\beta(1-\beta)} $, and the expansion for ${}_2F_1$ is given in terms of its power series as:
\begin{equation}
{ }_2 F_1[p, q, r ; z]=\sum_k \frac{\left(p\right)_k\left(q\right)_k}{\left(r\right)_k} \frac{z^k}{k!}
\end{equation}
The paper proceeds by factorizing the integrals over $\alpha$ and $\beta$ using standard techniques for integrals of the form:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 dx x^p \left(1-x\right)^q = \frac{\Gamma(1+p)\Gamma(1+q)}{\Gamma(2+p+q)}
\end{equation}
which they say can be handled easily in Mathematica or similar algebraic systems.
The final result they obtain for the function is:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Delta V_{\text{eff}}^{(c,d)}}{N} = \delta^2 \lambda^2 \frac{\eta^5}{30 \pi^3} \frac{4}{N} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{4N} \right) \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} + \frac{41}{10} - 4 \ln 2 - \frac{X}{2} - 3 \ln \frac{\eta}{M} \right)
\end{equation}
where $X \sim 1.63669$ is a constant obtained from the integrals.
Here's the code I wrote:
I started with the definition of the function $\frac{\Delta V_{\text{eff}}^{(c,d)}}{N}$:
deltaVeff[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Epsilon]_, \[Eta]_, \[Lambda]_, M_, n_, \[Delta]_] := (-4/n) (1 - 1/(4 n)) (\[Delta]^2 \[Lambda]^2 \[Eta]^5/(4 Pi)^(9/2)) (E^(EulerGamma) M^2/\[Eta]^2)^(3 \[Epsilon]/2) (Gamma[-5/2 + 3 \[Epsilon]/2] (2 - \[Epsilon])^2) ((Gamma[-1/2 + \[Epsilon]/2])^2/(Gamma[-1 + \[Epsilon]])) (\[Beta] (1 - \[Beta]))^(-3/2 + \[Epsilon]/2) Hypergeometric2F1[-1/2 + \[Epsilon]/2, 3/2 - \[Epsilon]/2, -1 + \[Epsilon], 1 - \[Alpha] (1 - \[Alpha])/(\[Beta] (1 - \[Beta]))]

Since Mathematica is unable to directly expand ${}_2F_1[\dots, 1 - z]$, I applied the following transformation to rewrite it in terms of ${}_2F_1[\dots, z]$ using the Pfaffian transformation (see Wikipedia):
TransHyp[a_, b_, c_, z_] := (1 - z)^(-a)  Hypergeometric2F1[a, c - b, c, z/(z - 1)];

Then, I used it as follows:
TransdeltaVeff[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Epsilon]_, \[Eta]_, \[Lambda]_, M_, n_, \[Delta]_] := (-4/n) (1 - 1/(4 n)) (\[Delta]^2 \[Lambda]^2 \[Eta]^5/(4 Pi)^(9/2)) (E^(EulerGamma) M^2/\[Eta]^2)^(3 \[Epsilon]/2) (Gamma[-5/2 + 3 \[Epsilon]/2] (2 - \[Epsilon])^2) ((Gamma[-1/2 + \[Epsilon]/2])^2/(Gamma[-1 + \[Epsilon]])) (\[Beta] (1 - \[Beta]))^(-3/2 + \[Epsilon]/2) (TransHyp[3/2 - \[Epsilon]/2, -(1/2) + \[Epsilon]/2, -1 + \[Epsilon], ((1 - \[Alpha]) \[Alpha])/((1 - \[Beta]) \[Beta])])

To expand ${}_2F_1[p,q,r;z] = \sum_k \frac{(p)_k (q)_k}{(r)_k} \frac{z^k}{k!}$, I defined:
BinHyp[p_, q_, r_, z_, k_] := (Binomial[p, k] Binomial[q, k])/Binomial[r, k]*z^k/(k!)

I rewrote the function using this expansion as follows:
ExpHypdeltaVeff[k_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Epsilon]_, \[Eta]_, \[Lambda]_, M_, n_, \[Delta]_] := -((2^(-9 - \[Epsilon]) E^((3 EulerGamma \[Epsilon])/2) (-1 + 4 n) (-((-1 + \[Beta]) \[Beta]))^(1/2 (-3 + \[Epsilon])) \[Delta]^2 (-2 + \[Epsilon]) (M^2/\[Eta]^2)^(3 \[Epsilon]/2) \[Eta]^5 \[Lambda]^2 Gamma[1/2 (-1 + \[Epsilon])] (2^\[Epsilon] Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[-1 + \[Epsilon]]  BinHyp[(3 - \[Epsilon])/2, 1/2 (-1 + \[Epsilon]), 3 - \[Epsilon], ((-1 + \[Alpha]) \[Alpha])/((-1 + \[Beta]) \[Beta]), k] - 4  Gamma[2 - \[Epsilon]/2]  Gamma[-(5/2) + (3 \[Epsilon])/2]  BinHyp[(3 - \[Epsilon])/2, 1/2 (-1 + \[Epsilon]), -1 + \[Epsilon], ((-1 + \[Alpha]) \[Alpha])/((-1 + \[Beta]) \[Beta]), k]))/(n^2 \[Pi]^5))

To compute each value of $k$:
serk0 = Assuming[{\[Eta] > 0 && \[Epsilon] < 1 && \[Epsilon] > 0}, FullSimplify[Integrate[ExpHypdeltaVeff[0, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Epsilon], \[Eta], \[Lambda], M, n, \[Delta]], {\[Alpha], 0, 1}, {\[Beta], 0, 1}]]]

serk1 = Assuming[{\[Eta] > 0 && \[Epsilon] > 3}, FullSimplify[Integrate[ExpHypdeltaVeff[1, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Epsilon], \[Eta], \[Lambda], M, n, \[Delta]], {\[Alpha], 0, 1}, {\[Beta], 0, 1}]]]

serk2 = Assuming[{\[Eta] > 0 && \[Epsilon] > 5}, FullSimplify[Integrate[ExpHypdeltaVeff[2, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Epsilon], \[Eta], \[Lambda], M, n, \[Delta]], {\[Alpha], 0, 1}, {\[Beta], 0, 1}]]]

serk3 = Assuming[{\[Eta] > 0 && \[Epsilon] > 7}, FullSimplify[Integrate[ExpHypdeltaVeff[3, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Epsilon], \[Eta], \[Lambda], M, n, \[Delta]], {\[Alpha], 0, 1}, {\[Beta], 0, 1}]]]

However, the integrals diverge, and I cannot get any finite expression to continue.
To compute the expansion for $\epsilon \to 0$, I did:
expepsk0 = Series[serk0, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]
expepsk1 = Series[serk1, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]
expepsk2 = Series[serk2, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]
expepsk3 = Series[serk3, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]

How can I reorder the sum to obtain the desired result? Should I sum them as follows?
expepsk0 + expepsk1 + expepsk2 + expepsk3

Any guidance on how to set up and evaluate these integrals correctly, or pointers to similar worked examples, would be greatly appreciated.

You want to solve this integral: Integrate[ ((1 - \[Beta]) \[Beta])^(-(3/2) + \[Epsilon]/2)*   Hypergeometric2F1[    3/2 - \[Epsilon]/2, -(1/2) + \[Epsilon]/2, -1 + \[Epsilon],     1 - ((1 - \[Alpha]) \[Alpha])/((1 - \[Beta]) \[Beta])], {\[Alpha],    0, 1}, {\[Beta], 0, 1}] ?

@MariuszIwaniuk I am unable to compute the integration to find Delta V; Mathematica indicates that the integrals are diverging. I might be making an error somewhere, and the one you mentioned is one of them.

This is not the answer to your question, only solution for integral:
$\int _0^1\int _0^1((1-\beta ) \beta )^{-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\epsilon }{2}} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\epsilon }{2},-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\epsilon }{2};-1+\epsilon ;1-\frac{(1-\alpha ) \alpha }{(1-\beta )
   \beta }\right)d\beta d\alpha =\\-\frac{\pi ^{3/2} \csc (\pi  \epsilon ) \Gamma \left(\frac{\epsilon }{2}\right) \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2} (-2+\epsilon ),\frac{1}{2} (-5+3 \epsilon
   );-\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon ;1\right)}{2 \Gamma \left(2-\frac{\epsilon }{2}\right)}+\frac{2 \pi ^2 \csc ^2(\pi  \epsilon ) \left(-2 (-2+\epsilon ) \, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,-1+\epsilon
   ;\frac{5}{2}-\frac{\epsilon }{2},1+\frac{\epsilon }{2};1\right)+(-3+\epsilon ) \epsilon  \, _3F_2\left(1,1-\frac{\epsilon }{2},-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\epsilon }{2};\frac{3}{2},3-\epsilon ;1\right)\right)
   \sin \left(\frac{\pi  \epsilon }{2}\right)}{\epsilon  \Gamma (4-\epsilon ) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\epsilon }{2}\right) \Gamma \left(-\frac{5}{2}+\frac{3 \epsilon }{2}\right)}$
for: $\epsilon<3$
f[\[Epsilon]_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[((1 - \[Beta]) \[Beta])^(-(3/2) + \[Epsilon]/2)*Hypergeometric2F1[
3/2 - \[Epsilon]/2, -(1/2) + \[Epsilon]/2, -1 + \[Epsilon], 
1 - ((1 - \[Alpha]) \[Alpha])/((1 - \[Beta]) \[Beta])], {\[Alpha], 0, 1}, {\[Beta], 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // Quiet

g[\[Epsilon]_] := N[-((\[Pi]^(3/2)
  Csc[\[Pi] \[Epsilon]] Gamma[\[Epsilon]/
  2] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1/2 (-2 + \[Epsilon]), 
  1/2 (-5 + 3 \[Epsilon]), -(1/2) + \[Epsilon], 1])/(
2 Gamma[2 - \[Epsilon]/2])) + (
 2 \[Pi]^2 Csc[\[Pi] \[Epsilon]]^2 (-2 (-2 + \[Epsilon]) \
 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1, -1 + \[Epsilon]}, {5/2 - \[Epsilon]/2, 
     1 + \[Epsilon]/2}, 
    1] + (-3 + \[Epsilon]) \[Epsilon] HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 
     1 - \[Epsilon]/2, -(1/2) + \[Epsilon]/2}, {3/2, 
     3 - \[Epsilon]}, 1]) Sin[(\[Pi] \[Epsilon])/
 2])/(\[Epsilon] Gamma[4 - \[Epsilon]] Gamma[
 3/2 - \[Epsilon]/2] Gamma[-(5/2) + (3 \[Epsilon])/2]), 20]

 {f[2], g[2 - 10^-5]}
 (*{2.7725887201378465184, 2.7726205198746292635}*)

 {f[3], g[3 - 10^-15]}
 (*1.0000000000000000000, 1.0000000000000009482*)

 {f[1 + 1/2], g[1 + 1/2]}
 (*5.4684039196073402370, 5.4684039196076099388*)

 Plot[g[\[Epsilon]], {\[Epsilon], -5, 5}](*Plot NOT Exist for: \[Epsilon] >= 3 *)


How I find the double integral:
From Here a Contour integral representations of Hypergeometric2F1[a,b,c,z]:
 ((1 - \[Beta]) \[Beta])^(-(3/2) + \[Epsilon]/
   2)*(1/(2 Pi I)) (Gamma[
     c]/(Gamma[a] Gamma[b] Gamma[c - a] Gamma[c - b]))*(Gamma[
      s] Gamma[s + c - a - b] Gamma[a - s] Gamma[b - s])/(1 - 
  z)^s /. a -> 3/2 - \[Epsilon]/2 /. b -> -(1/2) + \[Epsilon]/2 /. c -> -1 + \[Epsilon] /. z -> 1 - ((1 - \[Alpha]) \[Alpha])/((1 - \[Beta]) \[Beta])

 Integrate[%, {\[Beta], 0, 1}, {\[Alpha], 0, 1}]
 ((InverseMellinTransform[2 Pi I*Q2, s, A] /. A -> 1)[[1]]) // FullSimplify

 (*Answer it looks different but it is correct*)

EDITED 14.09.2024:
The final result for delta V:
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"];

DeltaV0[n_, \[Lambda]_, \[Eta]_, \[Delta]_, 
M_, \[Epsilon]_] := (1/(2*256 n \[Pi]^(7/2) Gamma[-1 + \[Epsilon]])
 E^((3 EulerGamma \[Epsilon])/
2) (1 - 1/(4 n)) \[Delta]^2 (-2 + \[Epsilon])^2 (M^2/\[Eta]^2)^(
3 \[Epsilon]/2) \[Eta]^5 \[Lambda]^2 Gamma[
 1/2 (-1 + \[Epsilon])]^2 Gamma[\[Epsilon]/
 2] ((Sqrt[\[Pi]]
    Csc[\[Pi] \[Epsilon]] Gamma[-(5/2) + (3 \[Epsilon])/
     2] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{-1 + \[Epsilon]/
      2, -(5/2) + (3 \[Epsilon])/2}, {-(1/2) + \[Epsilon]}, 1])/
  Gamma[2 - \[Epsilon]/2] - (
  Sqrt[\[Pi]]
    Csc[\[Pi] \[Epsilon]] Gamma[
    1/2 (-1 + \[Epsilon])] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, 
     1/2 (-1 + \[Epsilon]), 1 - \[Epsilon]/2}, {3/2, 
     3 - \[Epsilon]}, 1])/Gamma[\[Epsilon]/2] + 
  Gamma[-1 + \[Epsilon]] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, -1 + \[Epsilon], 1/2}, {1 + \[Epsilon]/2, 5/2 - \[Epsilon]/2}, 
    1] Sec[(\[Pi] \[Epsilon])/2]));

    DeltaV1[n_, \[Lambda]_, \[Eta]_, \[Delta]_, 
    M_, \[Epsilon]_] := \[Delta]^2*\[Lambda]^2*\[Eta]^5/(30*Pi^3)*4/n*(1 - 1/(4 n))*(1/\[Epsilon] + 41/10 - 4 Log[2] -Rationalize[1.63669, 0]/2 - 3 Log[\[Eta]/M]);

   N[{DeltaV0[2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1/10000], DeltaV1[2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1/10000]}, 20]

   (*{18.820556643299960242, 18.820553400643808517}*)


 m = 0; Series[
 DeltaV0[n, \[Lambda], \[Eta], \[Delta], 
  M, \[Epsilon]], {\[Epsilon], 0, m}] // Normal // N // 
 FullSimplify // Expand(*Asymptotic expansion at \[Epsilon]=0.*)

$$-\frac{0.00161258 \delta ^2 \eta ^5 \lambda ^2 \log \left(\frac{M^2}{\eta ^2}\right)}{n^2}+\frac{0.00645031 \delta ^2 \eta ^5 \lambda ^2 \log \left(\frac{M^2}{\eta ^2}\right)}{n}-\frac{0.000547485 \delta ^2 \eta ^5 \lambda
   ^2}{n^2}-\frac{0.00107505 \delta ^2 \eta ^5 \lambda ^2}{n^2 \epsilon }+\frac{0.00218994 \delta ^2 \eta ^5 \lambda ^2}{n}+\frac{0.0043002 \delta ^2 \eta ^5 \lambda ^2}{n \epsilon }$$
 DeltaV2[n_, \[Lambda]_, \[Eta]_, \[Delta]_, M_, \[Epsilon]_] := 
  Evaluate[Series[DeltaV0[n, \[Lambda], \[Eta], \[Delta], 
    M, \[Epsilon]], {\[Epsilon], 0, 0}] // Normal // N // 
 Simplify // Expand]

 Plot[{DeltaV0[2, 1, 1, 1, 3, \[Epsilon]], 
 DeltaV1[2, 1, 1, 1, 3, \[Epsilon]], 
 DeltaV2[2, 1, 1, 1, 3, \[Epsilon]]}, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1/3}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Black}, {Blue, DotDashed}}](*A nice plot*)

EDITED 15.09.2024:
Delta V asymptotic for $\epsilon \to 0$ simplier form almost similar to that written in the article.:
 DeltaV0[n, \[Lambda], \[Eta], \[Delta], M, \[Epsilon]] // 
FunctionExpand
Normal[
 Series[(2^(-7 - \[Epsilon]) (E^(((3 EulerGamma \[Epsilon])/
   2))) (-1 + 4 n) (\[Delta]^2) ((M^2/\[Eta]^2)^(
   3 \[Epsilon]/2)) (\[Eta]^5) (\[Lambda]^2)
    Csc[\[Pi] \[Epsilon]] (Gamma[-(1/2) + \[Epsilon]/2]^2) )/(
  n^2 \[Pi]^3 Gamma[
    2 - \[Epsilon]] Gamma[-1 + \[Epsilon]/2]), {\[Epsilon], 0, 
   1}]]*Asymptotic[ 
 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 
   1 - \[Epsilon]/2, -(1/2) + \[Epsilon]/2}, {3/2, 
   3 - \[Epsilon]}, 1], {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}] + 
 Normal[Series[(
  2^(-9 - \[Epsilon]) E^((3 EulerGamma \[Epsilon])/
   2) (-1 + 4 n) \[Delta]^2 (-2 + \[Epsilon])^3 (M^2/\[Eta]^2)^(
   3 \[Epsilon]/
    2) \[Eta]^5 \[Lambda]^2 Gamma[-(1/2) + \[Epsilon]/
     2] Gamma[-2 + \[Epsilon]] Sec[(\[Pi] \[Epsilon])/2])/(
  n^2 \[Pi]^3 Gamma[5/2 - \[Epsilon]/2] Gamma[
    1 + \[Epsilon]/2]), {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]]*
Asymptotic[ 
 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1, -1 + \[Epsilon]}, {5/2 - \[Epsilon]/2,
    1 + \[Epsilon]/2}, 1], {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}] - 
 Normal[Series[(
  2^(-6 - 2 \[Epsilon]) E^((3 EulerGamma \[Epsilon])/
   2) (-1 + 4 n) \[Delta]^2 (-2 + \[Epsilon]) (M^2/\[Eta]^2)^(
   3 \[Epsilon]/
    2) \[Eta]^5 \[Lambda]^2 Csc[\[Pi] \[Epsilon]] Gamma[-1 + \
  \[Epsilon]] Gamma[-(5/2) + (3 \[Epsilon])/2] Sin[(\[Pi] \[Epsilon])/
    2])/(n^2 \[Pi]^3 Gamma[-(1/2) + \[Epsilon]]), {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]]*Asymptotic[
  Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-2 + \[Epsilon]), 
  1/2 (-5 + 3 \[Epsilon]), -(1/2) + \[Epsilon], 1], {\[Epsilon], 
  0, 1}] // FullSimplify

  Series[%, {\[Epsilon], 0, 0}] // Normal //FullSimplify

  (*((-1 + 4 n) \[Delta]^2 \[Eta]^5 \[Lambda]^2 (240 + \ 
  [Epsilon] (637 - 840 Log[2]) + 
  360 \[Epsilon] Log[M^2/\[Eta]^2]))/(7200 n^2 \[Pi]^3 \ 
  [Epsilon])*)

$$\frac{\Delta V_{\mathrm{eff}}^{(c, d)}}{N}=\frac{\delta ^2 \eta ^5 \lambda ^2 (4 n-1) \left(360 \epsilon  \log \left(\frac{M^2}{\eta ^2}\right)+\epsilon  (637-840 \log (2))+240\right)}{7200 \pi ^3 n^2 \epsilon }=\\\frac{\delta ^2 \lambda ^2 \eta ^5 4 \left(1-\frac{1}{4 n}\right) \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon }+\frac{637}{240}-\frac{7 \log (2)}{2}-3 \log \left(\frac{\eta }{M}\right)\right)}{\left(30
   \pi ^3\right) n}$$
  DeltaV6[n_, \[Lambda]_, \[Eta]_, \[Delta]_, M_,\[Epsilon]_]:=\[Delta]^2 \[Lambda]^2 \[Eta]^5/(
  30 \[Pi]^3) 4/n (1 - 1/(4 n))*(1/\[Epsilon] + 637/240 - (7 
  Log[2])/2 - 3  Log[\[Eta]/M]);

  N[DeltaV6[2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1/10000], 20]

  (*18.820024904639153084*)


Let me clarify what you've done. Your function DeltaV0 seems to correspond to equation (B1) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.0676v3. However, you used HypergeometricPFQRegularized instead of Hypergeometric2F1. Are these two functions equivalent in this context? Additionally, it looks like you expanded DeltaV0 in terms of $\epsilon$ for $m = 0$ (to first order). It seems that HypergeometricPFQRegularized can be expanded in $\epsilon$ without any issues. Is that correct? @MariuszIwaniuk

@EverlinMartins. Yes,DeltaV0 correspond to equation (B1) ,but from aricle it follows that:  $\frac{\text{B1}}{2}=\text{B4}$.My solution for double integral is HypergeometricPFQRegularized.Yes are  equivalent both. You can expand HypergeometricPFQRegularized to Hypergeometric2F1 using: FunctionExpand command.If you use: m=1,or m=2, you get  long and complicated expression with
derivative Hypergeometric function that FullSimplify can't simplify.

Thanks for the update! I appreciate it. I have 1 question: In your latest update, you mentioned VV, but I couldn't follow it. Could you clarify more?

@EverlinMartins. 'VV' It consists of 3 terms of hypergeometric function ,then I use Asymptotic and Series of dose terms to get Asymptotical behavior at zero.

Thank you again! I appreciate your detailed explanations. God bless you!
